# Как можно программировать на чистом си для андройд?

Tags: android, c

Как можно программировать на чистом си для андройд? С чего начать? Язык си знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С изучения [ndk](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). Правда, насколько мне известно, так просто писать только на C не получится.  Придется использовать Java прослойку. Литературы в интернете валом. Вот к примеру, [первое попавшееся](http://suvitruf.ru/2013/02/02/2982/) и [второе](http://idev.by/android/21115/).

Comment: Если писать игры, то можно только на С. Если GUI - то писать только на C будет очень большим гемором.

Answer (score 0):

Весь код оборачивается в Java. Как понимаю, напрямую не получится.